# HBase Thrift End-Of-File Exception

Tags: hadoop, hbase, thrift

I am working on a Ruby project that is using HBase & Thrift through the [HBase Thrift Ruby](https://github.com/jeanlescure/hbase_thrift_ruby) gem.

While getting a scanner on the table using `scannerOpenWithScan`, I'm getting intermitent end-of-file exceptions from Thrift. That looks like this: `F, [2016-11-29T11:36:03.554884 #28744] FATAL -- : 
Thrift::TransportException (end of file reached):`

As I said, it's happening intermittently, even with the same query. Could it be something to do with the transport size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We notice that when attempting to resolve this issue.
When you have a connection open and there is no activity on it for longer than 60 seconds and then attempt to use it you get a `Thrift::TransportException (end of file reached)` error.

Currently our solution to this when it happens is to:

- `catch` the `Thrift::TransportException`
- check if it's a `end of file reached` error
- open a new connection
- then `retry`